# DirectDraw application goes black after screen orientation change

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, directdraw

I have a directdraw application (in c) that becomes black in color once the user rotates the screen using a button on the application. The button uses `enumdisplaysettings` to do this. I have tested this on both Nvidia and ATI, the problem persists.

Is there a way to make a directdraw application "displaysettings-proof"? Can I add some code to get back the display once the screen is rotated?

Comment: You may need to shutdown and reinitialise DirectDraw. I've not done this myself but overheard my colleague swearing at it lots.

Comment: You can add me to the list of people swearing. I wish there was a easier way. I am testing things a bit more before pursuing that route. Maybe it is something to do with the buffer. Running out of idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDirectDraw::RestoreDisplayMode to reset the display mode to whatever it was before IDirectDraw::SetDisplayMode was called. I'm not quite sure if this is what you want however.

Comment: Do I need to explicitly call IDirectDraw::RestoreDisplayMode before calling enumdisplaysettings? OR do I just set the IDirectDraw::RestoreDisplayMode once the screen has flipped?

Comment: Also I am on windows desktop not Win CE.